# QNetworkReplyHttpImplPrivate::_q_startOperation was called more than once

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkreply, qnetworkrequest

What happen with Qt?
In previous versions i didn't feel this problem.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtNetwork/QtNetwork>
QJsonObject loadJson() {
   QNetworkAccessManager manager;
   QNetworkRequest request(QUrl(QString("https://www.google.com")));
   QNetworkReply &reply = *manager.get(request);
   QEventLoop loop;
   QObject::connect(&manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit);
   loop.exec();
   return QJsonDocument::fromJson(reply.readAll()).object();
}
```

Output: QNetworkReplyHttpImplPrivate::_q_startOperation was called more than once QUrl("https://www.google.com") 
QJsonObject()
[Qt version (img)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLn2c.png)
MSVC 2017 x64. Same problem with MinGw.

Comment: You don't indicate what versions of Qt you were and are using. Please clarify.

Comment: Added Qt version.

Comment: I believe @metal was interested in the actual versions of the QT library, aka `5.x.y` or `4.x.y`.

Comment: Seems to work fine on Qt 5.3.0 (with some customizations, but not to Qt Network).

Comment: Might be this bug: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-72463